# Imported CSV data once, column recognized as integer; now they're text. Why did it change?

Tags: excel, vba, import

I've been working on a little VBA project; after importing data from a CSV file, I have VBA code that does things with it. I've written a bit of VBA code, but it's not my primary programming language.

The CSV file has two lines of text, then a line of text headers

```
"Name","Gender","18 Hole Index", ... ,"Total Slope","Total Par","Total Course Hdcp"
```

Then data:

```
"Doe, John","Male","23.45", ... ,116,71,18
```

I imported this through the Data,text/csv menu and got what I expected, including a column of integers under the last column.

I spent several days on my little VBA project and got it working.

But now, when I import the CSV file with the same characteristics as the first one I outlined above, it imports the last column as TEXT, and of course the VBA code doesn't work any more.

I can figure out how to convert it (eventually, VBA doesn't make that straightforward, different topic), but I want to know how I can do the import so that conversion is not necessary. I figure it's possible somehow, because it didn't require any conversion the first time. I did not do anything fancy on the original import; I did not do any transformations (I would have to look up how), I just imported data and this column was there as Integer data. What could have changed how that got imported, and how do I get back the original behavior?

EDIT: first 8 lines of data:

```
"Player Course Handicap"
" "
"Name","Gender","18 Hole Index","Course","Tees","Front Rating","Front Slope","Front Par","Front Course Hdcp","Back Rating","Back Slope","Back Par","Back Course Hdcp","Total Rating","Total Slope","Total Par","Total Course Hdcp"
"Doe, John","Male","23.45","River Ridge","Gold","33.6",115,36,10,"33.3",122,36,10,"66.9",119,72,20
"Doe, Jack","Male","20.78","River Ridge","Gold","33.6",115,36,8,"33.3",122,36,9,"66.9",119,72,17
"Doe, Jacques","Male","1.71","River Ridge","White","34.3",121,36,-1,"34.3",128,36,-1,"68.6",125,72,-2
"Doe, Jane","Male","25.07","River Ridge","Red","32.4",113,36,9,"31.7",111,35,9,"64.1",112,71,18
"Doe, Albert","Male","26.08","River Ridge","Gold","33.6",115,36,11,"33.3",122,36,11,"66.9",119,72,22
```

The actual data has actual names and goes on for 60-some lines. In both cases, the last column shows up as text, not integer.

Comment: You're more likely to get suggestions if you post the code you're using.

Comment: But my question does not involve code, it involves importing data. It appears that at one time the import produced integers in the columnn in question, and another time it produced text. I have shown what the data being imported looks like. There's no VBA code to show. Is there something else you think I ought to be showing?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood that you were using VBA to import the data. If you open the file directly (via file >> open) does it open correctly?

Comment: Why do you have `vba` tag if, as you write, the problem has nothing to do with vba? If you are using the `Data=>From Text/CSV` and not doing any transform on the input, it may be that there is data in the first 200 or so rows that is being interpreted as text rather than numbers in that last column in the similar file. Might be simplest to use the `Transform Data` option at the bottom of the dialog to fix that, and you might be able to accomplish your VBA tasks using that same tool.

Comment: @TimWilliams You are right, my apologies for including the VBA tag. I'm using VBA in the project, but it is not related to this problem.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes, shouldn't have included VBA, sorry about that. The first two lines in the file have a single text string, then there's a line of data headers that are all text strings, then 56 lines of data, a mix of strings and numbers. The 17th column of data is all signed integers, values from -4 to 37. I still don't know why it's screwing it up, especially since I swear it did it right the first time I tried it.

Comment: How are you getting rid of those first two lines of data? Please post a data sample as text which will demonstrate the problem when it is pasted into a text file and imported as per your method.

Comment: You did not indicate how you got rid of those first two rows. They are probably the reason the columns are being characterized as text. At least, that is what is happening here. You could delete those two lines before you import or, use the 'Transform' option in the dialog to set things up properly.

Comment: I did not get rid of the first two rows. The first time I imported the data, with these columns in place, it imported that 17th column as Integer. I wrote a bunch of VBA code, some of which assumed it was Integer, and it worked until I imported another file. I did not get rid of or transform anything in the first file; I did not want the users of the VBA to have to mess with it (they aren't programmers themselves), and don't even know how to do the transform (obviously I tell it to use Integer for the column, but my first attempt at that failed, I'd have to look it up).

Comment: Let's back up a bit. If you are just importing the data, using the Excel User Interface, and writing it directly to an excel worksheet, all of the numerical data will be formatted as `General`. (Excel does not have an Integer data type). What makes you think the values are input as text strings? *(I wonder if this might turn out to be a problem with your VBA code, rather than a problem with your import process)*

Comment: Sorry, get used to programming and forget Excel just has 'number', not integer. No, no VBA involved; just the import. Each cell has a data type; a text string made up of digits is left-justified in the cell; a number is right-justified. I didn't notice at first because I don't look at the worksheet much, I've been looking at VBA code. But when I tried to do arithmetic (in VBA) with a cell containing a text string of digits, it threw an error.

Comment: I found the problem, creating an answer now. Wait 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the anomaly.

If you OPEN the CSV with Excel (just double-click the CSV file to open it), Excel transforms columns containing mostly digits to numbers.

If you open Excel and execute Data=>Get Data=>From Text/CSV, it does NOT transform such columns to numbers. I was writing my VBA based on a file I had opened, not imported, assuming that "data import" and "open file" would get the same results.

Now I wish there were some (simple) way to import the data and have Excel apply the same transforms on the import that it applies to data when reading the file.

I know one can alter the transforms done by the import, by clicking "Transform Data" on the import popup and replacing "text" with "number" in that transform formula or whatever it is. But I'm creating something to be used by people for whom that is much too sophisticated, and so in my situation it is better to take the default text import and convert it in the VBA.

Thanks to all who were looking into this with and for me.

Comment: You could automate that entire process in either Power Query or in classic VBA.  Instead of having your users select `Data/From Text/CSV`, merely have them press a button which activates the appropriate query. You can then use input boxes or a user form to guide them through whatever data they need to provide and do the import in VBA, and then the processing in VBA.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, and might do it yet. So far my users are able to import a file, just not alter a long statement with braces and quotes and all those other things programmers take for granted.